# $\text{sin}(\sqrt{x+4n^2\pi^2})\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Show that $\text{sin}\sqrt{x+4n^2\pi^2}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Intuitively, it makes sense to me since $x+4n^2\pi^2$ is approximately $4n^2\pi^2$ for large $n$, but I want to be sure I can show this formally. $\frac{x+4n^2\pi^2}{4n^2\pi^2}\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$, $\frac{x+4n^2\pi^2}{4n^2\pi^2}=\epsilon(n)$, where $\epsilon(n)\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$.

So $\underset{n\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\text{sin}(\sqrt{x+4n^2\pi^2})=\underset{n\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\text{sin}(\sqrt{4n^2\pi^2\epsilon(n)})=\text{sin}(\sqrt{\underset{n\to\infty}{\text{lim}}4n^2\pi^2\underset{n\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\epsilon(n)})=\text{sin}(\sqrt{\underset{n\to\infty}{\text{lim}}4n^2\pi^2})=\underset{n\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\text{sin}(\sqrt{4n^2\pi^2})=0$

Does this look correct? Thank you

Comment: $n$ is assumed to be an integer

Comment: @TomChalmer: You can write `\sin` for the sine and `\lim_{n \to \infty}` for the limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument is not correct. 
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} \sin \sqrt{4n^2\pi^2 \epsilon(n)} = 
  \sin \sqrt{\lim_{n \to \infty} 4n^2\pi^2 \epsilon(n)}
$$
assumes that
$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sin x$ exists, and that is not the case.

But you can use the mean value theorem.
Since $|\sin'(x)| = |\cos (x)| \le 1$ we have for fixed $x \in \Bbb R$
and all sufficiently large $n \in \Bbb N$ (such that $ x+4n^2\pi^2 \ge 0$):

$$
|\sin(\sqrt{x+4n^2\pi^2})| = |\sin(\sqrt{x+4n^2\pi^2}) - \sin(\sqrt{4n^2\pi^2}) |\\
 \le \left | \sqrt{x+4n^2\pi^2} - \sqrt{4n^2\pi^2} \right |\\
 = \frac{|x|}{\sqrt{x+4n^2\pi^2} + \sqrt{4n^2\pi^2}} 
 \to 0
$$
for $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin\sqrt{x+4n^2\pi^2}-\sin2n\pi=2\sin\frac{\sqrt{x+4n^2\pi^2}-2n\pi}{2}\cos\frac{\sqrt{x+4n^2\pi^2}+2n\pi}{2}=$$
$$=2\sin\frac{x}{2\left(\sqrt{x+4n^2\pi^2}+2n\pi\right)}\cos\frac{\sqrt{x+4n^2\pi^2}+2n\pi}{2}\rightarrow0$$